# "Different fields of study" or "studies"

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

Which one is correct?

> Different fields of study

or

> Different fields of studies

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to say. Please tell us.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to use this phrase is either:

> Different field of study

(if speaking of one field of study), or

> Different fields of study

(if speaking of more than one field of study)

Answer (score 1):

The word study in this context is an uncountsble noun that means the act or activity of learning or gaining knowledge.

So the correct phrase is as follows:

Different fields of study.

As the word field is a countable noun,you can also use it in the singular as follows:

A different field of study.